# Pass response from server to display it for end user

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build the following and I am learning JS as I go, so I would appreciate some guidance and explanation on how to approach the following:
I have two pages, one with client-side script, that takes an uploaded image, converts it to base64 and fetches it to the second page, where the server-side script uploads it to a location via API.

This is the fetch on my first page:

```
        fetch("xxxxxx", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    fileEnc: fileEnc,
                    fileName: fileName,
                    fileType: fileType
                })
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log("Success!", res);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Error!", err);
            });
    };
```

On my second page, an API call is made and I get the following response:

```
console.log(uploadImage.StatusCode)
```

My question is:
**How do I pass the response back to my first page and how do I display it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Second page should write the status code in the response rather than in the console. And that text will be available in the "then" part of the fetch function.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that?

Comment: currently the response logged by .then is a 200 and it's a response from passing the data to my processing page. How do I change it so that it's actually the response from the API call on my processing page?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the second page was opened from the first page, write a function in the first page where you want to consume that data which is executed from the second page with the data you need as an argument:

page 1

```js
function logData(data) {
  console.log('@data from api: ', data)
}
```

page2

```js
// some code here
window.opener.logData(dataFromApi)
```